# Change xml file to pipe demilited using unix

Tags: linux, unix

Input file:

```
<Response>
<Status>SUCCESS</Status>
<CustDtls>
<HeaderDtlsList>
<HeaderDtls>
<CustNbr>1001</CustNbr>
<SalesNbr>260236</SalesNbr>
<RowSequenceNbr>0</RowSequenceNbr>
<LineItemType>Header</LineItemType>
<CName>Alex</CName>
<CustomerType>PRO</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>1988-05-08</DateOfBirth>
<CostAmt>$110.9800</CostAmt>
</HeaderDtls>
<HeaderDtls>
<CustNbr>1001</CustNbr>
<SalesNbr>260239</SalesNbr>
<RowSequenceNbr>0</RowSequenceNbr>
<LineItemType>Header</LineItemType>
<CName>Seneta</CName>
<CustomerType>DIY</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>1900-01-01</DateOfBirth>
<CostAmt>$17.4000</CostAmt>
</HeaderDtls>
</HeaderDtlsList>
<ContactList>
<Contact>
<CustNbr>1001</CustNbr>
<SalesNbr>260243</SalesNbr>
<RowSequenceNbr>1</RowSequenceNbr>
<LineItemType>Contact</LineItemType>
<PhoneNumber>114-5099940</PhoneNumber>
<ExtensionNumber>123</ExtensionNumber>
</Contact>
<Contact>
<CustNbr>1001</CustNbr>
<SalesNbr>261942</SalesNbr>
<RowSequenceNbr>1</RowSequenceNbr>
<LineItemType>Contact</LineItemType>
<PhoneNumber>668-4958486</PhoneNumber>
<ExtensionNumber> </ExtensionNumber>
</Contact>
</ContactList>
</CustDtls>
</Response>
```

Current output using below command:

```
 cat testxml.txt | perl -ne '/<\/HeaderDtls>/ && print "\n"; />(.*?)</ && !/<SalesNbr>/  && print $1."|"; /<SalesNbr>/ && /SalesNbr>?(.*?)<\/.*?(LineItemType>?)(.*)?<\/LineItemType/ && print $1."|".$3' > Header.txt
```

cat Header.txt

```
SUCCESS|1001|0|Header|Alex|PRO|1988-05-08|$110.9800|
1001|0|Header|Seneta|DIY|1900-01-01|$17.4000|
1001|1|Contact|114-5099940|123|1001|1|Contact|668-4958486| |
```

**Expected output:**

Need Header details in separate file `Header.txt` without the word **SUCCESS** and without contact details. 
  Eg:

```
1001|0|Header|Alex|PRO|1988-05-08|$110.9800|
1001|0|Header|Seneta|DIY|1900-01-01|$17.4000|
```

Also Need Contact details in separate file `contacts.txt`

```
1001|1|Contact|114-5099940|123|
1001|1|Contact|668-4958486| |
```

Could anyone resolve this?

Comment: you could process the Header.txt file further.. `sed -i.bkp 's/^SUCCESS\|//' Header.txt` to remove SUCCESS.. and then `grep -w 'Header' Header.txt > header.txt` , `grep -w 'Contact' Header.txt > contact.txt` .. but I feel there might be some xml parser to do all this in a better way

Comment: Yes that invloves two more steps. One to remove the word success then second step to grep for word Header and move to new file. Looking for single command which can be modified in the above perl command to achieve the same.